# Problem using accessors in V8

Tags: c++, v8, embedded-v8

I'm writing a wrapper class around the V8 engine so that eventually I'll be able to do something like this

```
script->createClass("Test");
script->getClass("Test")->addFunction("funct1",testfunct1);
script->getClass("Test")->addVariable("x",setter,getter);
```

So far I can create classes and add functions to them and it works perfectly, however I have encountered a problem with adding variables.

My class template is stored as such

```
Persistent<Object> classInstance;
```

and I try to add an Accessor like this:

```
this->classInstance->SetAccessor(String::New(variableName),setter,getter);
```

Compiling this code gives me the error that v8::Object doesn't have a SetAccessor function (though I've seen doxygen documentation that says otherwise).

So my question is: How can I fix this?  Is it possible to cast an Object to an ObjectTemplate?

Comment: Can you show us the exact error you're seeing? And the V8 version you're using? I do see a `SetAccessor` method on `Object` in the version I have here, which is 2.5.7.

Comment: What kind of knuckle-head names his product after a version number?  Oh, wait...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`SetAccessor` on `Object` is available as of V8 2.2.12, which was released May 2010. (Before that, it was indeed only available on `ObjectTemplate`.) You should probably update your copy of V8.